# Select Where Month= X and Year= Y

Tags: sql, t-sql, datepart

I have the following select:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Column= datepart(month,'2013-05-07 10:18:00') 
  AND Column= datepart(year,'2013-05-07 10:18:00')
```

I want it to show me itens where month= 05 and year= 2013. Actually it isn't showing anything (but there is results to be show). Thanks.

Comment: You're comparing both the month and year to `Column`.  Are you sure you're not using the same column in your actual `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Why people vote down? I did not said my code was correct. I just put what I was doing and asking for help!

Comment: how about reading the documentation before posting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq in "What kind of questions can I ask here?" did not ask me to read the documentation before ask a question. Stay cool, dude.

Comment: All is cool. But a simple read of the documentation before posting on here would have directed you on the correct path. Glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use the MONTH and YEAR functions

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE MONTH(yourColumn) = 5  and YEAR(yourColumn) = 2013
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx

Comment: Definitely use this, it's better than my answer. Good job you waited those 3 minutes :-)

Comment: @TheWaxMann No, there is actually no difference at all between them. This is translated to use `datepart`. You can see that if you look at the xml version of the queryplan. And to be honest. They are equally bad and will always have to scan all rows in the table to figure out what rows to return. There is no way this will use an index.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table
 WHERE datepart(month, datecolumn) = 5
   AND datepart(year, datecolumn) = 2013
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as answered :-)

Comment: yeah, SO ask me to wait some minutes... 3 to go...

Answer (score 2):

Applying functions on columns is genrally a bad idea. It makes the condition [non-sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Better to test on an interval.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateCol >= '20130501' AND
      DateCol < '20130601'
```

[A SQL Fiddle to play around with that proves my point](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9d61/3)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE month = DATE_FORMAT('2013-05-07 10:18:00', '%m') AND ...
```

Comment: Your answer is in MySQL; the OP is using t-sql.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine your column is itself a DATE?
Then you need to apply DATEPART on both sides of the "="

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM Table
    WHERE
        DATEPART(MONTH, Column)= DATEPART(MONTH,'2013-05-07 10:18:00') 
        AND DATEPART(YEAR, Column) = DATEPART(YEAR,'2013-05-07 10:18:00')
```